# economics.stackexchange.com is not properly moderated

Tags: support, moderation, closed-questions

[Can a small reward control big money exchange rates?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/45503/17919)

> Closed. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers.
>
> Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new one.

I've accomplished the moderator's requirements, but the question isn't unclosed. Why?

Comment: I recommend changing the title of this meta post to: "The decentralized review process of economics.stackexchange.com is oppressing my crypto question, please help me central authority."

Answer (score 5):

First, the requirements are not moderator requirements they part of site rules and the site is moderated by all high rep members not just moderators. It is not necessarily moderator job to review your contribution, if other users do not reverse their closing vote.

Furthermore, moderators on stack exchange sites are volunteers and we do not guarantee speedy moderation. Consequently, just because your question is not opened immediately after it is edited does not mean the site is not properly moderated.

In addition, I find that the question still lacks details and clarity you just included some extra information about your project that does not even seem relevant.

In your question you ask if "small reward" can control "big money exchange rates", what is here "small reward"? What are "big money exchange rates"? This is not economic terminology so you need to explain what you even mean by that. How do you define small reward in economic terms? Is it some monetary reward if so what is small \$100 \$10,000 or \$100,000?

Next, in the body of a question you state:

> Let we have a prediction market. Suppose the prices of some conditionals became high because it bubbled so much that people started to use the conditionals as means of payment.

> I want to control this big market of conditionals using only a small (e.g. 1-5% of the big market) amount of some collateral (e.g. dollars or bitcoin) to pay to conditional owners at the end of the prediction period.

Again you need to add details of clarity, what are the conditionals you are talking about here? Also what do you mean by controlling the "big market of conditionals"?

Next you ask:

> Is this possible? At first it would seem impossible, but in Russia the CB was able to control the dollar-rouble rate by publishing recommended exchange rate. Considering existing practical economical knowledge of similar situations, will our small collateral donations likely control the big market? Is this control stable? How much part of the value of the big market we need to control well?

What are your references for the first statement? Next again how you define small collateral donation and control over a market?

Lastly, the last two new paragraphs you included do not seem to add any clarification at all of your question so you should either consider removing them or explaining how they relate,